# The specific .BLEND file does not open, blender simply closes on execution

Tags: import, blend-files

I have a problem that is bothering me. I use blender 2.79 and, when trying to open a specific .BLEND file, it just closes, without any explanation of the crash. I've tried to open it in several ways, using .BLEND1, dragging it to the window and it just closes when opening that specific file. But when opening other files, they open normally, so the problem is happening exclusively with my file, I don't know if my file is corrupted or the problem is blender, so I'm here to ask for help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share the blend file?  Also, have you tried opening it with later versions of blender?

Comment: If the file has been overwritten in a more recent version, (eg 2.93) it may not open on older versions. If you open the file with the notepad the first few characters will be unencrypted and show you the version it has been saved as.